# Optimizing c++ code to add two numbers taken as string

Tags: c++, optimization, biginteger

I've been working on a function that reads two strings having digits and print the sum of two. Example if I pass "100" and "99" through my function, it prints "199". I'm doing it to deal with numbers which are say 100 digits long. Many implementations using operator overloading and classes do exist online to handle such big integers but I don't want that much level of sophisticated codes. I just want to write basic +,-,/,* and % operations. I've written down the following code for addition. But I feel I should optimize it further. Any tips regarding optimizing the below code and how to apply multiplication, division and % operators in an optimized way?

```
char* Add(char *s1,char *s2)
    {
        char *A,*B;
        int L1=strlen(s1),L2=strlen(s2),La,Lb,i;
        if(L1>=L2)
        {
            A=s1; La=L1;
            B=s2; Lb=L2;
        }
        else
        {
            A=s2; La=L2;
            B=s1; Lb=L1;
        }
        int L=La+2;
        char s[L];
        s[L-1]='\0';
        s[0]='0'; int temp=0;
        for(i=0;i<Lb;i++)
        {
            int x=((int)(A[La-1-i]-'0')+(int)(B[Lb-1-i]-'0'));
            s[L-2-i]=(char)((x+temp)%10+'0');
            temp=x/10;
        }
        for(i=La-Lb-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            int x=(int)(A[i]-'0');
            s[L-La+i-1]=(char)((x+temp)%10+'0');
            temp=x/10;
        }
        s[0]=(char)(temp+'0');
        char *sum = s[0]!='0' ? &s[0] : &s[1];
        return sum;
   }
```

Problems:

When in main function I write something like

```
char *c=(char*)Add("99","10"); 
c=(char*)Add(c,"10");
std::cout<<c;
```

It prints junk values.

When in main function I write something like :

```
char *c=(char*) Add("999999999999999999999999999","10000");
std::cout<<c;
```

I'm getting junk values although printing "sum" in the function itself gives correct output.

Some points about my program:

1. A is longer of two strings s1 and s2 and B is shorter of two.
2. La is length of A and Lb is length of B.
3. s is string storing final result with length L = (La+1)+1 because output can be atmost 1 digit longer than A.
4. sum points to first charcter of s[1] in case result is as long as A and s[0] if result is one character longer than A.
   Example:
   If A=100 B=99, then s=0199 and thus sum points to s[1].
   If A=99 B=99, then s=198 and thus sum points to s[0].

Comment: To start with, you might want to consider converting the strings to numbers instead (see e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)). Then start using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of character pointers, this is especially important considering that you return a pointer to a local variable (which leads to *undefined behavior*)

Comment: But c++ won't be able to handle a 100 digit number.

Comment: If you want to do maths with large numbers, which cannot be represented in an int or long, you might want to use a library such as https://gmplib.org/. It won't be easy to write anything more optimized than that.

Comment: You might also want to check out libraries such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), if you have values larger than can be handled natively.

Comment: Is there any way to get handle the undefined behaviour of the local variable to which I'm returning the character pointer.

Comment: @CPPCoder Yes, don't use pointers! Use `std::string`. You *are* coding in C++ are you not? Use the facilities that are provided to you in the [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) when you can, it will make your life as a C++ program so much simpler and easier.

Comment: Actually using string with lengths as high as say 10^6 gives memory error or segmentation faults on many compilers. That's why I'm not avoiding it.

Comment: You use `std::string` with a length of a million characters? I think you might want to reconsider your design! But it shouldn't give you crashes unless you do something weird with the strings.

Comment: In my experience, `std::string` should work for the size supported by the hardware - which is "how much memory" and "how many bits does `size_t` hold" - obviously the total size of all strings must be less than the amount of memory available - but on a machine with, say, 4GB of memory and where `size_t` is 32 bits, you should EASILY cope with strings that are 10^6. At least as long as you don't try to multiply two such strings - that makes a string that is 10^12 digits long, and that could start getting into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted, I'm guessing the issue is that `sum` is allocated on the stack.  As such, it's only guaranteed to be valid for the lifetime of its enclosing scope (ie, your `Add` function).  You should instead allocate a new character buffer on the heap and return it.  Eg.,

```
char* s = new char[L];
```

---

Edit: As others have pointed out, you might consider using a string instead of a character array.  They're a little more friendly.

That said, if you don't want to use a string, given your code, the above solution could leak memory (the first character if s starts with '0').  Instead, you could go with your original code, modifying the end as follows.

```
    char* sum;
    if (s[0] == '0')
    {
        sum = new char[strlen(s)];
        strcpy(sum,s+1);
    }
    else
    {
        sum = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        strcpy(sum,s);
    }
```

Again, the big issue seems to be that `s` and `sum` are local to your function.  This means that after your function executes, the runtime is free to reuse their memory.  What using `new` allows you to do is to assign memory to the "heap," which will not be overwritten by the runtime until you free the associated memory.  [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)'s a quick tutorial explaining the basic idea.

---

Edit 2: As a commenter pointed out below, an off-by-one error might have caused an overflow.  I've edited the code above to get rid of the issue.  However, it's a good example of why it may have been a better idea to use `std::string` in the first place.

Comment: Seeing the OP's level of knowledge with memory management details, I'd suggest using std::string first.

Comment: I'm using *sum because I want to remove s[0] based on the fact whether it's 0 or not. I tried declaring *sum globally but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I tested it before posting.  A big part of C/C++ is understanding where the logical data reside in memory and the lifetime associated with data.  It can be really confusing.  I tried to link to a post about why the above change would fix your code.  But if you have any other questions, feel free to follow up below and I'll try to answer next time I see them (I'm going to bed now).

Comment: Doing `new char[strlen(s)]` and then a string-copy will cause a buffer overflow when `strcpy` adds the string terminator. Don't forget it when using raw C-style strings and pointers. Another reason that using `std::string` will help.

Comment: @Joachim, you're right.  That's embarrassing.  Thank you for pointing it out.  I'll edit the code above in case anyone stumbles on it in the future.  It's a great example of why using string in the first place is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment saying "use `std::string`" - in total, the overhead is not much more than using manual allocation with `malloc(L)` or `new char[L]`, and it has the benefit of allowing you to "fire and forget" complex expressions, such as:

```
std::string a = "102";
std::string b = "192312";
std::string c = Add(a, Add(b, Add(a, Add(b, a))));
```

Obviously, I'm assuming you will want to do generic math, not just add, in which case the above makes more sense, e.g. `c = Add(a, Mul(a, b))` would do `c = a + a * b;`

If you do the above complex calls using manual allocation, you would have to store all the intermediate values, and then free them when they are no longer needed, such as:

this:

```
std::string c = Add(a, Add(b, Add(a, Add(b, a))));
```

becomes:

```
char *tmp1 = Add(b, a); 
char *tmp2 = Add(a, tmp1); 
delete [] tmp1;   // Assuming we use `new`, otherwise `free tmp1` if using `malloc`. 
char *tmp3 = Add(b, tmp2);
delete [] tmp2;
char *c = Add(a, tmp3); 
... do stuff with c
delete [] c;
```

The `std::string` also keeps track of the actual length, which means `strlen` is no longer "expensive" - `std::string::length()` is a very simple function with a complexity of O(1) - where `strlen()` is O(n) - that is, the time it takes is proportional to the length of the string.

Comment: Yes you are right. string implementation will be more convinient. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To give suggestions for improvement (the other half of your question), then I'd suggest to stop doing so much unnecessary calculations.  Like e.g.

```
for(i=0;i<Lb;i++)
{
    int x=((int)(A[La-1-i]-'0')+(int)(B[Lb-1-i]-'0'));
    s[L-2-i]=(char)((x+temp)%10+'0');
    temp=x/10;
}
```

can better be written as:

```
int ib,ia,is;
for (
    int ib = Lb-1, int ia = La-1, int is = L-1; 
    ib >= 0; 
    ib--, ia--, is--
) {
    int x=((int)(A[ib]-'0')+(int)(B[ib]-'0'));
    s[is]=(char)((x+temp)%10+'0');
    temp=x/10;
}
```

which saves you all those `La-1-i` calculations every pass through the loop, and they also make the code clearer (IMHO).

Another point is to drop the (int) and (char) casts; they're not needed.

A third point is not to use division and modulo if you can help it - they're potentially relatively lengthy operations.  In this loop you know the addition of 2 digits can at most be 18, so doing a `x/10` is far too complicated, and can be replaced with a simple if-like structure, like `temp = x>9? x-10: x`.  Same goes for the %.

A more design-wise decision you could take is about the constant conversion between the textual and numeric representation of the digits.  If your big-int-strings spend more time inside calculations than in input/output, then it might be wise to pre- and post convert them only once.  So a textual string is first mapped into it's numeric form (each char -= '0'), then with this form you do all your calculations, and only before you output it again you make all digits textual again (each char += '0').

And yet another (micro) optimization: don't use post-fix -- when the pre-fix version will do as well, so use --ia instead of ia-- here.  x-- has some overhead because it returns x's value before it got decremented, which leads to code like `int temp = x, --x, return temp`.

Comment: The optimisation of `%` to `x>9?x-10:x` is probably a bigger gain than breaking out the different index calculations, as compilers tend to figure that sort of thing out quite well (in fact, introducing more variables can be detrimental in this respect).

Comment: @MatsPetersson: ah, didn't know that, thanks!  But I find breaking out the indices (in stead of calculating them) is also an improvement in readability.  In fact, if it were me I'd give all variables a much more descriptive name anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is of course a different matter - if the code is readable, that's generally better.

Comment: Thanks! I'll appy these optimizing tips

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want to implement division and modulo operators properly, then you should store the number as "raw data" instead of ASCII format (in other words, represent it on base-2 instead of base-10).

Below is my implementation for a class that stores a natural number of any conceivable size. It supports any arithmetic operation provided by C++, and provides an interface for converting the number to / from an ASCII string on any base (up to base-36, since there are no more digits and letters beyond that).

The number is maintained as little-endian, but the code is compatible with both types of architectures.

Here is how you can use it in order to implement your `char* Add(char *s1,char *s2)` function:

```
NaturalNum n1 = StringToNaturalNum(s1,10);
NaturalNum n2 = StringToNaturalNum(s2,10);
NaturalNum sum = n1+n2;
int s1len = strlen(s1);
int s2len = strlen(s2);
char* str = new char[MAX(s1len,s2len)+2];
sum.ToString(str,10);
return str;
```

And here is the implementation of the `NaturalNum` class itself:

**File NaturalNum.h:**

```
#ifndef NATURAL_NUM_H
#define NATURAL_NUM_H


class NaturalNum
{
public: //Constructors + Destructor
    NaturalNum();
    virtual ~NaturalNum();
    NaturalNum(unsigned int iNaturalNum);
    NaturalNum(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Assignment Operators
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator+=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator-=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator*=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator/=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator%=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator|=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator&=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator^=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator<<=(unsigned int iShift);
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator>>=(unsigned int iShift);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Unary Operators
    virtual NaturalNum operator~() const;
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator++();
    virtual const NaturalNum& operator--();
    virtual NaturalNum operator++(int dummy);
    virtual NaturalNum operator--(int dummy);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Binary Operators
    friend NaturalNum operator+(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator-(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator*(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator/(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator%(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator|(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator&(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend NaturalNum operator^(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    virtual NaturalNum operator<<(unsigned int iShift) const;
    virtual NaturalNum operator>>(unsigned int iShift) const;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Binary Comperators
    friend bool operator<(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend bool operator>(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend bool operator==(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend bool operator<=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend bool operator>=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    friend bool operator!=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public: //Interface Routines
    unsigned int BitCount() const;
    void ToBuffer(unsigned char aBuffer[]) const;
    void ToString(char aString[],unsigned int iBase) const;
    friend NaturalNum StringToNaturalNum(const char aString[],unsigned int iBase);
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
protected: //Internal Routines
    void Allocate(unsigned int iBytes);
    void DeallocateAll();
    void RemoveRedundantZeros();
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
protected: //Object Attributes
    unsigned int   m_iLength;
    unsigned char* m_aValues;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
};


#endif
```

**File NaturalNum.cpp:**

```
#include "NaturalNum.h"


///////////////////////////////////////
// Constructors + Destructor (below) //


NaturalNum::NaturalNum()
{
    Allocate(0);
}


NaturalNum::~NaturalNum()
{
    DeallocateAll();
}


NaturalNum::NaturalNum(unsigned int iNaturalNum)
{
    Allocate(sizeof(iNaturalNum));

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m_iLength; i++)
        m_aValues[i]=iNaturalNum>>(i*8);

    RemoveRedundantZeros();
}


NaturalNum::NaturalNum(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    Allocate(0);
    *this=cNaturalNum;
}


// Constructors + Destructor (above) //
///////////////////////////////////////


//////////////////////////////////
// Assignment Operators (below) //


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    if (this==&cNaturalNum)
        return *this;

    DeallocateAll();
    Allocate(cNaturalNum.m_iLength);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m_iLength; i++)
        m_aValues[i]=cNaturalNum.m_aValues[i];

    return *this;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator+=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this+cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator-=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this-cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator*=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this*cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator/=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this/cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator%=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this%cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator|=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this|cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator&=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this&cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator^=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum)
{
    return *this=*this^cNaturalNum;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator<<=(unsigned int iShift)
{
    return *this=*this<<iShift;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator>>=(unsigned int iShift)
{
    return *this=*this>>iShift;
}


// Assignment Operators (above) //
//////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////
// Unary Operators (below) //


NaturalNum NaturalNum::operator~() const
{
    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(m_iLength);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=~m_aValues[i];

    return cRes;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator++()
{
    *this+=1;
    return *this;
}


const NaturalNum& NaturalNum::operator--()
{
    *this-=1;
    return *this;
}


NaturalNum NaturalNum::operator++(int dummy)
{
    NaturalNum cRes=*this;
    *this+=1;
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum NaturalNum::operator--(int dummy)
{
    NaturalNum cRes=*this;
    *this-=1;
    return cRes;
}


// Unary Operators (above) //
/////////////////////////////


//////////////////////////////
// Binary Operators (below) //


NaturalNum operator+(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2.m_iLength<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum2+cNaturalNum1;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cNaturalNum2.m_iLength+1);

    unsigned int   i;
    unsigned short iSum;
    unsigned char  iRem=0;

    for (i=0; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
    {
        iSum=iRem+cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]+cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=iSum&0xFF;
        iRem=iSum>>8;
    }
    for (; i<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; i++)
    {
        iSum=iRem+cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=iSum&0xFF;
        iRem=iSum>>8;
    }
    cRes.m_aValues[i]=iRem;

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator-(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2>cNaturalNum1)
        throw "Negative Result";

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cNaturalNum1.m_iLength);

    unsigned int i;
    signed short iDif;
    signed char  iRem=0;

    for (i=0; i<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; i++)
    {
        iDif=iRem+cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]-cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=iDif&0xFF;
        iRem=iDif>>8;
    }
    for (; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
    {
        iDif=iRem+cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i];
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=iDif&0xFF;
        iRem=iDif>>8;
    }

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator*(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    NaturalNum cRes=0;

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; j++)
            cRes+=(NaturalNum)(cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]*cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[j])<<((i+j)*8);

    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator/(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2==0)
        throw "Infinite Result";

    NaturalNum cRes=0;

    NaturalNum cTmp1=cNaturalNum1;
    unsigned int iTmp1Len=cTmp1.BitCount();
    unsigned int iNaturalNum2Len=cNaturalNum2.BitCount();

    while (iTmp1Len>iNaturalNum2Len)
    {
        cRes+=(NaturalNum)1<<(iTmp1Len-iNaturalNum2Len-1);
        cTmp1-=cNaturalNum2<<(iTmp1Len-iNaturalNum2Len-1);
        iTmp1Len=cTmp1.BitCount();
    }

    if (cTmp1>=cNaturalNum2)
        return cRes+1;

    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator%(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    return cNaturalNum1-cNaturalNum1/cNaturalNum2*cNaturalNum2;
}


NaturalNum operator|(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2.m_iLength<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum2|cNaturalNum1;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cNaturalNum2.m_iLength);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]|cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
    for (; i<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=0|cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator&(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2.m_iLength<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum2&cNaturalNum1;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cNaturalNum2.m_iLength);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]&cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
    for (; i<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=0&cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum operator^(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum2.m_iLength<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum2^cNaturalNum1;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(cNaturalNum2.m_iLength);

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i]^cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];
    for (; i<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength; i++)
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=0^cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i];

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum NaturalNum::operator<<(unsigned int iShift) const
{
    unsigned int iByteShift=iShift/8;
    unsigned int iBitsShift=iShift%8;

    if (m_iLength==0)
        return 0;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(m_iLength+iByteShift+1);

    for (unsigned int n=0; n<iByteShift; n++)
        cRes.m_aValues[n]=0;

    unsigned int  i;
    unsigned char iRem=0;
    for (i=iByteShift; i<m_iLength+iByteShift; i++)
    {
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=(m_aValues[i-iByteShift]<<iBitsShift)|iRem;
        iRem=m_aValues[i-iByteShift]>>(8-iBitsShift);
    }
    cRes.m_aValues[i]=iRem;

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


NaturalNum NaturalNum::operator>>(unsigned int iShift) const
{
    unsigned int iByteShift=iShift/8;
    unsigned int iBitsShift=iShift%8;

    if (m_iLength<=iByteShift)
        return 0;

    NaturalNum cRes;
    cRes.Allocate(m_iLength-iByteShift);

    unsigned int  i;
    unsigned char iRem;
    for (i=0; i<m_iLength-iByteShift-1; i++)
    {
        iRem=m_aValues[i+iByteShift+1]<<(8-iBitsShift);
        cRes.m_aValues[i]=(m_aValues[i+iByteShift]>>iBitsShift)|iRem;
    }
    iRem=m_aValues[i+iByteShift]>>iBitsShift;
    cRes.m_aValues[i]=iRem;

    cRes.RemoveRedundantZeros();
    return cRes;
}


// Binary Operators (above) //
//////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////
// Binary Comperators (below) //


bool operator<(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum1.m_iLength!=cNaturalNum2.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum1.m_iLength<cNaturalNum2.m_iLength;

    for (unsigned int i=cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i>0; i--)
        if (cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i-1]!=cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i-1])
            return cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i-1]<cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i-1];

    return false;
}


bool operator>(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum1.m_iLength!=cNaturalNum2.m_iLength)
        return cNaturalNum1.m_iLength>cNaturalNum2.m_iLength;

    for (unsigned int i=cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i>0; i--)
        if (cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i-1]!=cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i-1])
            return cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i-1]>cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i-1];

    return false;
}


bool operator==(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    if (cNaturalNum1.m_iLength!=cNaturalNum2.m_iLength)
        return false;

    for (unsigned int i=cNaturalNum1.m_iLength; i>0; i--)
        if (cNaturalNum1.m_aValues[i-1]!=cNaturalNum2.m_aValues[i-1])
            return false;

    return true;
}


bool operator<=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    return !(cNaturalNum1>cNaturalNum2);
}


bool operator>=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    return !(cNaturalNum1<cNaturalNum2);
}


bool operator!=(const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum1,const NaturalNum& cNaturalNum2)
{
    return !(cNaturalNum1==cNaturalNum2);
}


// Binary Comperators (above) //
////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////
// Interface Routines (below) //


unsigned int NaturalNum::BitCount() const
{
    if (m_iLength==0)
        return 0;

    unsigned int iBitCount=(m_iLength-1)*8;
    for (unsigned int i=1; i<=m_aValues[m_iLength-1]; i<<=1)
        iBitCount++;

    return iBitCount;
}


void NaturalNum::ToBuffer(unsigned char aBuffer[]) const
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m_iLength; i++)
        aBuffer[i]=m_aValues[i];
}


void NaturalNum::ToString(char aString[],unsigned int iBase) const
{
    unsigned int iIndex=0;

    for (NaturalNum cTmp=*this; cTmp>0; cTmp/=iBase)
    {
        NaturalNum cDigit=cTmp%iBase;
        if (cDigit==0)
            aString[iIndex]='0';
        else if (cDigit<10)
            aString[iIndex]='0'+cDigit.m_aValues[0];
        else
            aString[iIndex]='A'+cDigit.m_aValues[0]-10;
        iIndex++;
    }

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<iIndex/2; i++)
    {
        char iDigit=aString[i];
        aString[i]=aString[iIndex-1-i];
        aString[iIndex-1-i]=iDigit;
    }

    if (iIndex==0)
        aString[iIndex++]='0';

    aString[iIndex]=0;
}


NaturalNum StringToNaturalNum(const char aString[],unsigned int iBase)
{
    NaturalNum cRes=0;

    for (unsigned int i=0; aString[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        NaturalNum cDigit;
        if ('0'<=aString[i] && aString[i]<='9')
            cDigit=aString[i]-'0';
        else if ('A'<=aString[i] && aString[i]<='Z')
            cDigit=aString[i]-'A'+10;
        else if ('a'<=aString[i] && aString[i]<='z')
            cDigit=aString[i]-'a'+10;
        else
            break;
        cRes*=iBase;
        cRes+=cDigit;
    }

    return cRes;
}


// Interface Routines (above) //
////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////
// Internal Routines (below) //


void NaturalNum::Allocate(unsigned int iBytes)
{
    m_iLength=iBytes;
    if (m_iLength>0)
        m_aValues=new unsigned char[m_iLength];
}


void NaturalNum::DeallocateAll()
{
    if (m_iLength>0)
        delete[] m_aValues;
    m_iLength=0;
}


void NaturalNum::RemoveRedundantZeros()
{
    while (m_iLength>0 && m_aValues[m_iLength-1]==0)
        if (--m_iLength==0)
            delete[] m_aValues;
}


// Internal Routines (above) //
///////////////////////////////
```